# Finding text between two strings while containing a certain value

Tags: regex

I've run into a problem when trying to find text between two strings while containing a certain value.

**I have a text string (see below):**

```
[ { "_attributes": { "id": "3190.7999" }, "jobs**": { "_attributes": { "count": "1" }, "CRJob": { "_attributes": { "id": "519" }, "jobID": "519", "toStatusNode": { "CRDataNode": { "_attributes": { "id": "4583" }, "dataNodeID": "4583" } } } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2966.7999" }, "**jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2953.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2952.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2764.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2629.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2607.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "1096.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "1078.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "1034.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "960.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "1" }, "CRJob": { "_attributes": { "id": "238" }, "jobID": "238", "toStatusNode": { "CRDataNode": { "_attributes": { "id": "4585" }, "dataNodeID": "4585" } } } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "844.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "638.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "633.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "601.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } } ]
```

**Target:** I would like to return all text between “jobs” and “jobs” but only for the part where this text contains "4583". For the example above this would mean I would like to return:

```
": { "_attributes": { "count": "1" }, "CRJob": { "_attributes": { "id": "519" }, "jobID": "519", "toStatusNode": { "CRDataNode": { "_attributes": { "id": "4583" }, "dataNodeID": "4583" } } } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2966.7999" }, "jobs": { "_attributes": { "count": "0" } } }, { "_attributes": { "id": "2953.7999" }, "
```

I’ve tried this: `(?<=jobs).*(?=jobs)`

But this returns everything between the first and last “jobs”.  I am unsure as to what I need to add to be able to only get the part that contains “4583”.

How would I be able to do it?

Comment: JSON is parsed with dedicated tools and it is not regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

`(?<=jobs\")(?=.*4583.*).*?(?="jobs)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/INcsq5/2)

Comment: @Thomaso 1) This is not going to help you in case `4583` appears after both `jobs`, 2) you should really abandon the idea of parsing JSON with regexps, it is not good even for regex practicing. It is pointless.